# Array modifier does strange things with mesh

Tags: modifiers

I am attempting a very simple (or so I thought) mesh to make the base for a laser cutter table. It is simply a tweaked square with an extended base.

I used the solidify and bevel modifier to give it a little depth and rounded edges.

When I went to put the array modifier on it to duplicated it, the first piece of the array didn't show up. And the second piece gives me both together for some reason. See the gif for the behavior.

Also, the problem seems to go away when I unclick "merge". But, it doesn't really merge them so the bevel modifier still makes them appear to be separate pieces.

What is the best practice here?

Any idea what is going on?

[image: Array modifier out of control]

Answer (score 3):

It is very likely that merge distance is set too high. Array modifier behaves unexpectedly when the merge distance is larger than the object. Try applying the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and setting the merge distance to a reasonable value. That should be all that's need to fix this.

Modifier order does change the result, however they should work correctly in any order.

[image]